# Debugging threads in Xcode for iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, gdb

When debugging in a thread created with an NSOperationQueue I can set breakpoints just fine, but actual crashes result in the thread silently dying.  This is in the simulator, but it also happens on the hardware itself.

Is there a setting in Xcode (gdb, really) that will catch these?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would start by adding these two lines to your ~/.gdbinit file:

```
fb objc_exception_throw
fb -[NSException raise]
```

This will pop you into the debugger and you should see the stack trace leading to the exception.

Comment: Just wanted to add a comment about this one.  It indeed works exactly as I was hoping.  Thanks!